# Exit on heap corruption without dialogue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

In unit tests, which may run on unattended build machines, it's not great to have "unittest.exe has stopped working" and other dialogues pop up on debug breaks. I've used the below functions to suppress most of these, and `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`, `signal` and so on to install handlers which print the test that failed, and a stack trace.

```
_set_abort_behavior(0, _WRITE_ABORT_MSG); // Disable abort message.
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE); // CRT asserts go to stderr.
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR); // CRT asserts go to stderr.
```

Unfortunately though, I'm finding that whilst printing messages or the stack trace after an error, sometimes heap corruption is detected which brings up the "unittest.exe has stopped working" dialogue. This is already inside my unhandled exception filter so understandably it can't call that again!

Is there a way to suppress this behaviour, and instead just exit straight away with a custom error code? Or perhaps a smarter way to handle this kind of case?

Comment: You could use SetUnhandledExceptionFilter().  Do avoid giving diagnostics, it is too risky.  Test failed, a dev can rerun it.  Do consider looking around for a better test runner.

Comment: I'm already using SetUnhandledExceptionFilter; it's within the handler that the heap corruption happens :) I'll edit to make that more explicit. I'm using unittest++, though I can't imagine any test runner is going to handle this kind of thing - it would be far too intrusive a thing to do.

Comment: As I mentioned, don't do much in the filter.  You can't rely on anything, the process heap may well be left locked.  A good way to make it very reliable is to just call SetEvent() on a named event.  Picked up by a guard process that reports failure and kills the process.